# How to make Odd Even LinkedList factor in the last node?

Tags: c++, c++11

Im trying out a leetcode question 328. Odd even linked list.
We are required to rearrange the below list to put all the odd nodes together and them the even nodes together. For example:

```
1->7->3->2->4
```

And then need to rearrange them to link the odd placed with the odd and then add the even at the end

```
1 3 4 7 2
```

However my issue is, when dealing with a list of even number of nodes, it leaves the last even number at the end of the odd numbers
For instance

```
5 7 4 3 9 8 2 1
```

and my code rearranges it to

```
5 4 9 2 1 7 3 8
```

but the answer should be

```
5 4 9 2 7 3 8 1
```

How can i fix the code for it to consider the last even number as an even number instead of odd?

```
if (head->next == NULL || head->next->next == NULL)
      return head;

    ListNode *odd = head;
    ListNode *even = head->next;
    ListNode *evenHead = even;

    while (even != NULL && even->next != NULL){
      odd->next = even->next;
      odd = odd->next;
      even->next = odd->next;
      even = even->next;
    }
    odd->next = evenHead;
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Looks good! Almost there!

- This'd pass:

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();


static const struct Solution {
    ListNode* oddEvenList(ListNode* head) {
        if (!head) {
            return head;
        }

        ListNode* odd = head;
        ListNode* even_head = head->next;
        ListNode* even = even_head;

        while (even && even->next) {
            odd->next = odd->next->next;
            even->next = even->next->next;
            odd = odd->next;
            even = even->next;
        }

        odd->next = even_head;

        return head;
    }
};
```

- `c++` variable naming is usually [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). It's OK to consistently use other styles though.